# Flickering cursor on some monitors

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, multiple-monitors, cursor

My cursor is flickering on two of my three monitors on every screen update.
I just had a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64-bit), and now that all screens are properly setup, I noticed that my cursor seems to be flickering.

I already tried to disable the gnome-settings-daemon cursor plugin and doing a restart, but it doesn't seem to be making a difference.